# Single-click to open folder on desktop not working on Xubuntu

Tags: xubuntu

I've enabled single-click for opening files, folder etc. It is working normally inside a folder but i still need to double-click on files/folder on desktop. Please advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Desktop icons are displayed by xfce4-desktop, not by the Thunar file manager, unlike the gnome and unity desktops. This is due to change in future releases, but for now there is nothing you can do.

[Additional information]

If you update to Xubuntu 12.04, the option to single click on desktop launchers / files is now there. It has been back-ported from the new version of XFCE, which will be available in Xubuntu 12.10.